# Can you run Elasticsearch with Loki?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, grafana-loki

I have elastic configured with Grafana and it has logs. I tried to query logs for the elasticsearch in grafana but did not have much succes. I went online to try to learn how to do so, but when I do it talks about Loki. Are you able to use Loki with Elasticsearch? Do not see a definite answer for this online.

Comment: you went online? did you mean online course?

Comment: I went online as in opened up the internet, sorry for the confusion @hamidbayat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Loki with ES defeats the purpose of using Loki itself.

Loki prides itself on indexing only the metadata/labels of the logs and storing the actual log data separately in a compressed manner.

This reduces storage costs and leads to faster retrieval of data as there is less data to index as compared to the an ES index which indexes everything in a log line and worse still ,if the data is missing ,stores the index attribute as empty. (Almost similar to the diff between SQL vs NoSQL)

As of now, Loki does not support ES as the index store.

It uses two types of indices:- Labels and log chunks and stores them separately to be queried as and when required.

Label/metadata/index :- uses Cassandra,GCS,File System,S3

Data chunks:- Cassandra,BigTable,DynamoDB,BoltDB

For more info see [Loki storage](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/storage/#notable-mentions).